# How to computer camera FOV given corresponding points in world space and view space

Tags: projective-geometry

The context might be an old photograph of (say) soldiers in a trench or a picnic in a forest, but without a horizon or any vanishing points.

My conjecture is that 4 known points in world space mapping to 4 points in projected image space are enough, with the constraint that the points form a solid object and a quadrilateral respectively.

The aim is eventually to find the location of the camera and its field of view, to reproduce the scene in software.

Am I right, and if so how to perform the calculation?

Comment: Your _tl;dr conjecture_ about 4 points needed is [shown here](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photogramm%C3%A9trie#Bases_g%C3%A9om%C3%A9triques) with 3 points.

Comment: Are you sure? That link appears to relate to Stereophotogrammetry, for which I can readily believe fewer points are needed.

Comment: I guess, your "4 point conjecture" is well thought out to serve as convincing _ansatz_.

Comment: What I find hard to believe is that this problem has not already attracted interest and found a solution.